# Inverse of a conditional CDF involving Copula

Tags: copula

I am planning a Monte-Carlo simulation exercise involving Gaussian Copulae. I have $n$ random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$ with known CDFs $F_i(x)$ (the CDFs are known but can not be described by formulas, the same is true for their inverses).

The random variables are linked through a Gaussian Copula with known parameters. I need to simulate $X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2},...,X_1$. For this I guess I would need to find $x_i=F^{-1}_{X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2},...,X_1}(u)$ as an algorithm mapping $u \in [0,1]$ to $x_i$.

My question is whether (given that I work with quite analytically tractable Gaussian Copula) I will be able to find such an algorithm at all or the whole idea is not going to work anyway and there is not sense for me to dig into the topic of Copulae any longer?

Comment: Do you mean that the $X_i$'s are of the form$$X_i=F_i^{ -1}(\Phi(Y_i))$$where$$(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\sim\mathcal{N}_n(0_n,\Sigma)$$

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, I guess it is another way to say that $X_i$s are linked through a Gaussian Copula (a more precise way).

Comment: I think you are familiar with the book [Roger B. Nelsen, An Introduction to Copulas, Second Edition. Springer 2006: Section 2.9, Random Variate Generation][1] [1]: http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387286594-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-163613-p70196476